# alert when element belong to parent jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this arrangement:

```
<ul id="Threads">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="clickme"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="Comments">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="clickme"></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).on('click','.clickme', function(){

      //something like this...
    $(this).closest("ul#Threads") alert("yes");

   });
```

I want it to show up an alert only when clicking the `li` that belong to `#Threads` parent

Comment: Change `.on('click','.clickme'` to `.on('click','#Threads .clickme'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it! Try like so:

```js
$(document).on('click','.clickme', function(){
    if($(this).closest("ul#Threads").length >= 1) {
        alert("yes");
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Threads">
  <li>Threads</li>
  <li>Threads</li>
  <li class="clickme">Threads</li>
</ul>

<ul id="Comments">
  <li>Comments</li>
  <li>Comments</li>
  <li class="clickme">Comments</li>
</ul>
```

or another way is to use `return`

```js
$(document).on('click','.clickme', function(){
    
    if($(this).closest("ul#Threads").length <= 0) {
        return;
    } 
    
    alert("yes");
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Threads">
  <li>Threads</li>
  <li>Threads</li>
  <li class="clickme">Threads</li>
</ul>

<ul id="Comments">
  <li>Comments</li>
  <li>Comments</li>
  <li class="clickme">Comments</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: both answer are almost the same, both works but yours has something extra, a plus _You almost had it!_ lol . thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```js
  $(document).on('click','.clickme', function(){

     if($(this).closest("ul#Threads").length) alert("yes");

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Threads">
  <li>Threads</li>
  <li>Threads</li>
  <li class="clickme">Threads</li>
</ul>

<ul id="Comments">
  <li>Comments</li>
  <li>Comments</li>
  <li class="clickme">Comments</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can also do the following

```
$(document).on('click','ul#Threads .clickme', function(){
   alert("yes");
});
```